# Determine if ActiveRecord used an index during lookup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any way, `using the console` to determine if a database lookup used an index?

example: `User.where(name: 'Bob', state: 'Delaware').first`

Is there a way to determine if an index was used to quickly find this?

I have added indexes but want to verify they are being used for certain lookups.

Thanks

Comment: You can do `User.where(name: 'Bob', state: 'Delaware').explain` to get the db to explain the query

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check with this:

```
User.where(name: 'Bob', state: 'Delaware').explain
```

Keep in mind that an index doesn't make query faster all the times, in some cases an index may make a query run slower, and some databases try to identify this, and may nor even use this index.

Check the cardinality of the index:

https://www.lullabot.com/articles/slow-queries-check-the-cardinality-of-your-mysql-indexes

Take care!

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain